Failed boot mounting /sysroot mount: unknown filesystem type 'ext4'
Background:
I have a Rocky Linux 8 (Rhel based) System.  The HW does not support UEFI so it is legacy.  However the drive is GPT so there is a grub partition at the beginning.  The partitions were XFS.  I tried to rsync all the data out (from the root partition), the repartition and format using ext4. Then copy the files back.
I'm trying to boot.
I booting with a rocky linux boot disk.  mounting the root partition and the boot partition.  bind mounting dev,proc,sys.  chroot.  Then I ran "dracut -f" followed by "grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg" then "grub2-install /dev/sda"  On mkconfig I got errors about device-mapper but since I am no longer using LVM I assumed this was not an issue.
It gets to grub and starts to boot but it fails trying to mount sysroot saying "unknown filesystem type 'ext4'"

What is sysroot?
Why wouldnt it know 'ext4' even after running dracut.

I'd appreciate any advice

Get to know about initrd / initramfs. /sysroot is likely where the "real root" mounted before switching root from the initramfs. Sounds like your initramfs is broken in one way or another that the ext4 driver module is missing or cannot be loaded successfully (like version not matching the kernel that was loaded by grub)

Just out of curiosity, has it always been called "/sysroot"  Anyways, my initial thought was that an initramfs issue.  That is why I booted with a boot disk and ran "dracut -f".  This usually fixes this type of issue.  The system was a bit of an odd setup because it was legacy/GPT with the grub partition.  Anyways, this took so long, I ended up just reinstalling the OS.  Probably the better choice given I didn't setup the original
